# SKProductRequest synchronous

Tags: cocoa, storekit

i start the product request already in a operation block

```
NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
      SKProductsRequest * request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: selectedSKIdentifiers];

      request.delegate = self;

      [request start];

}];
```

so i would like to use some synchronous version, like when downloading data

```
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

or parsing XML is also synchronous

```
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
[parser release];
```

**Is there a way for to do the SKProductsRequest synchronous**

The apple documentation luck on further info on this topic at this day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way how to make any method synchronous :

```
// create the object that will perform an async operation
MyConnection *conn = [MyConnection new];

// create the semaphore and lock it once before we start
// the async operation
self.theLock = [NSConditionLock new];

// start the async operation
self.testState = 0;
[conn doItAsyncWithDelegate:self];

// now lock the semaphore - which will block this thread until
// [self.theLock unlockWithCondition:1] gets invoked
[self.theLock lockWhenCondition:1];

// we're done
[self.theLock release];
[conn release];
```

Make sure to invoke!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
[self.theLock unlockWithCondition:1];
```

In the delegate(s) then.